# JavaScript (node js) skips empty cell while reading the Excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I'm doing a small task that to read Excel sheet and save in json format. The code I have used is working well when all the cell values present, if there is any empty cell it skip that cell.

The output which i want if any value is not presented (in my case I missed the cust2 phone Number) is given below.

`[ { cust_name: 'Ben',
    cust_city: 'Street1',
    cust_country: 'country1',
    phno: 1 },
  { cust_name: 'Ken',
    cust_city: 'street2',
    cust_country: 'country2' 
    phno:},
  { cust_name: 'Ron',
    cust_city: 'street3',
    cust_country: 'country3',
    phno: 3 } ]`

But The output I got is

`[ { cust_name: 'Ben',
    cust_city: 'Street1',
    cust_country: 'country1',
    phno: 1 },
  { cust_name: 'Ken',
    cust_city: 'street2',
    cust_country: 'country2' },
  { cust_name: 'Ron',
    cust_city: 'street3',
    cust_country: 'country3',
    phno: 3 } ]`

It missed the `phno` filed for the cust2.

Please Help me to to figure out what I have to change in my code to get my desired output.

My code is

```
 var XLSX = require('xlsx');
 var workbook = XLSX.readFile('customer.xlsx');
 var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
 sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y) {
 var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[y];
 var headers = {};
 var data = [];
 for(z in worksheet) {
    if(z[0] === '!') continue;
    //parse out the column, row, and value
    var col = z.substring(0,1);
    var row = parseInt(z.substring(1));
    var value = worksheet[z].v;

    //store header names
    if(row == 1) {
        headers[col] = value;
        continue;
    }
    if(!data[row]) data[row]={};
    data[row][headers[col]] = value;
 }
 //drop those first two rows which are empty
 data.shift();
 data.shift();
 console.log(data);
 });
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what if the first row has all the values and second row has some value missing?

Comment: I need to say that, there are some missed values in the rows. I want to show that filed is missed if it empty.

Comment: That is the problem with npm 'xlsx' module. I too was facing the issue. Nwz if the first row has all the fields, then i guess it will work well i guess. Try it once

Comment: Yeah sure, I will try it again. Thank You

Comment: After lot of trails, I still struggling with my problem, Can anyone HELP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue,
and on having gone through the library documentation the solution to the above issue was passing optional param to XLSX.readFile function.

i.e changing

from: var workbook = XLSX.readFile('customer.xlsx');

**to:**  **var workbook = XLSX.readFile('customer.xlsx', *{sheetStubs: true}*);**

The **sheetStubs** param in the optional object allows the library to list the cells which by default are ignored by data processing utilities of the library.

** Go through following sections of the library [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

1)Parsing Options
2)Data types (emphasise on data type z).

Comment: The above did allow me to at least access the rest of the json object except its undefined cells, without adding it my array would just end at the first empty element. I need to update an element now so I need to be able to fetch the empty cell 'values'. Another important part so far was using the !null in my filter function as referenced here https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/139#issuecomment-390754486.  My array is still returning with no values for the objects from the empty value. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but why is a custom method written to create the JSON? Doesn't sheet_to_json do the job? Is there anything I am missing here?